# Compare two dates in JSTL

Tags: jstl

I am comparing current date with a given date(from database in yyyy-MM-dd format) in jstl, but it is comparing only dd part not complete date dd-MM-yyyy. For example if current date is 29-06-2016 and I compare with 30-06-2018, it is comparing only 29 with 30. My code is:

```
<c:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />
<fmt:formatDate var="currDate" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" value="${now}" />
<fmt:parseDate value="${mat_list.dt_expiry_date}" var="parsedExpDate" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <fmt:formatDate var="expiryDate" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" value="${parsedExpDate}" />

        <c:if test="${currDate > expiryDate}"><b><span style="background-color: red; color: white">${expiryDate}</span></b></c:if>
```

How to compare full date with current date.

Comment: Compare Dates, not Strings. Dates are sorted in chronological order. Strings are sorted in lexicographic order. Also, put that code in your controller or model, not in the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below. Use either scriptlet or JSTL.

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US" />
<fmt:parseDate value="${mat_list.dt_expiry_date}" var="parsedExpDate" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
<c:if test="${now.time gt parsedExpDate.time}">
    <b><span style="background-color: red; color: white">${parsedExpDate}</span></b>
</c:if>
```